# CRS problem after raster reproject via QGIS Warp

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system

I have a land cover raster downloaded from NLCD website with CRS as `**EPSG: 42303** - NAD 83/Albers NorthAM`. I reprojected it to `**EPSG: 102740**, Texas State Plane South Central Zone 4204` via Warp of QGIS. However, when I check the the reprojected new raster CRS, it shows its CRS as

> **USER:100030** - * Generated CRS (+proj=lcc +lat_1=28.38333333333333 +lat_2=30.28333333333334 +lat_0=27.83333333333333 +lon_0=-99 +x_0=600000 +y_0=3999999.999999999 +datum=NAD83 +units=us-ft +no_defs) - Projected.

Should not it be **EPSG 102740** as I directed Warp to do?

Or how I can fix this bug (if it is a bug of QGIS Warp).

Answer (score 1):

There is no EPSG:102740 as you can check from https://www.epsg-registry.org/. It is actually a code defined by ESRI https://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102740/. However, GDAL does know what it means and is using EPSG:102740 as a synonym in reading.

```
gdalsrsinfo epsg:102740

PROJ.4 : +proj=lcc +lat_1=28.38333333333333 +lat_2=30.28333333333333 +lat_0=27.83333333333333 +lon_0=-99 +x_0=600000 +y_0=3999999.999999999 +datum=NAD83 +units=us-ft +no_defs

OGC WKT :
PROJCS["NAD_1983_StatePlane_Texas_South_Central_FIPS_4204_Feet",
    GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",
        DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
            SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",1968500.0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",13123333.33333333],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-99.0],
    PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",28.38333333333333],
    PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",30.28333333333333],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",27.83333333333333],
    UNIT["Foot_US",0.3048006096012192],
    AUTHORITY["Esri","2278"]]
```

The CRS that QGIS saves as USER:100030 has all correct parameters and it should work just fine for you.